# Find MA$(\infty)$ representation for an ARMA(2,2) process

Tags: time-series, arima

Given process $X_t$ with $Z_t$ being iid. $N(0,1)$: $$X_t+1,9X_{t−1}+0,9X_{t−2}=Z_t+0,4Z_{t−1}−0,6Z_{t−2}$$
If the process is causal then find the MA$(\infty)$ representation.

$$\Phi(z) = 1+1.9z+0.9z^2 =0.4z-0.6z^2 = 1+1.5z+0.3z^2 $$

I think I already made an error in this step. How to find the characteristic polynomial for this process and the inverse $\frac{1}{\phi(z)}$?

Comment: Let B be the lag operator such that $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}, ~ B(Y_t) = Y_{t-1}$. 

One can rewrite this equation using polynoms in term of B :

$\phi(B)(X_t) = \psi(B)(Z_t)$ where $\phi(X) = I - 1.9X + 0.9X^2$ and $\psi(X) = I + 0.4X - 0.6X^2$.

A ARMA process is said to be *causal* if all the roots of $\phi$ are outside the open unit disc.

Here one can check easily that $1$ and $\frac{1}{0.9}$ are roots of $\phi$...

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function (I/O relationship) can be written as (assuming the form $ \phi(z)X_t = \theta(z)Z_t $)
$$\begin{align}T(z)&=\frac{\theta(z)}{\phi(z)}=\frac{1+0.4z-0.6z^2}{1+1.9z+0.9z^2}=\frac{(1-0.6z)(1+z)}{(1+0.9z)(1+z)}\\&=\frac{1-0.6z}{1+0.9z}=\frac{5/3}{1+0.9z}-2/3\\&=5/3(1-0.9z+(-0.9z)^2...)-2/3, & \text{s.t.}\ \ \  |0.9z|<1\\&=1+5/3(-0.9z+(-0.9z)^2 +...)\end{align}$$

This translates into the following relation between $X_t$ and $Z_t$:
$$X_t=Z_t + {5\over3}\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-0.9)^i Z_{t-i}$$